# Write a method that accesses to a parametric dimension numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'm using **python 2.7** and **numpy 1.9**.
I have 3 methods that applies a transformation to a couple of numpy arrays.

```
def sum_arrays2(a, b):
    c = np.zeros(a.shape)
    c[:, 0:-1] = (a[:, 1:] + b[:, 0:-1]) ** 2
    return a[0:-1, 1:] + c[1:, 0:-1]

def sum_arrays3(a, b):
    c = np.zeros(a.shape)
    c[:, :, 0:-1] = (a[:, :, 1:] + b[:, :, 0:-1]) ** 2
    return a[0:-1, :, 1:] + c[1:, :, 0:-1]

def sum_arrays4(a, b):
    c = np.zeros(a.shape)
    c[:, :, :, 0:-1] = (a[:, :, :, 1:] + b[:, :, :, 0:-1]) ** 2
    return a[0:-1, :, :, 1:] + c[1:, :, :, 0:-1]
```

As you can see, they are very similar. The only difference is the required input array size.
Depending on the size of my data, I have to call the first one, the second or the third.

Actually I have to do something like this:

```
if a.ndims == 2:
  result = sum_arrays2(a, b)
elif a.ndims == 3:
  result = sum_arrays3(a, b)
elif a.ndims == 4:
  result = sum_arrays4(a, b)
```

How can I make a more general method that computes this for n-dimensional inputs?

The only solution I found is something like this:

```
def n_size_sum_arrays(a, b):
    c = np.zeros(a.shape)
    c[(Ellipsis, np.r_[0:c.shape[-1]-1])] = (a[(Ellipsis, np.r_[0:a.shape[-1]])] + b[(Ellipsis, np.r_[0:b.shape[-1]])]) ** 2
    return a[(r_[0:a.shape[0]-1], Ellipsis, np.r_[1:a.shape[-1]])] + c[(np.r_[1:c.shape[0]], Ellipsis, np.r_[0:c.shape[-1]-1])]
```

But it absolutely unclear and I'm not sure that it's correct.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
def sum_arrays(a, b):
    c = np.zeros(a.shape)
    c[..., :-1] = (a[..., 1:] + b[..., :-1]) ** 2
    return a[:-1, ..., 1:] + c[1:, ..., :-1]
```